# How to add additional markdown content to Dokka-generated (Kotlin KDoc) documentation?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, kotlin-dokka, kdoc

I'm trying to add additional documentation pages (not tied to a class or package element) to a Dokka-generated documentation tree. I know that I can add a `module.md` or a file for each package, but if I want to add additional pages (e.g. an onboarding guide, etc) is there a way to write a separate `user-guide.md` (or equivalent) and include it in the documentation tree?